# Setting up Windows 8 to use wifi for TeamViewer, but I want the Web-browser to connect to internet over a 3G-dongle

Tags: networking, wireless-networking, wifi-configuration, 3g, dongle

Searched all over the net but can't find an answer.

Hope someone here has the knowledge to help.

I have a laptop which I connect to remotely using TeamViewer. The Laptop has connection to WIFI and uses a 3g dongle. I'd like for all of the services and programs in the computer to use the Wifi-connection except for the web browser which I want to only use the 3G dongle-connection to connect to the internet.

How do I set it up?

The laptop is running Windows 8.1. Web-browser is either Chrome or Firefox.

The reason is that I want my internet-traffic through the browser to have the IP from the 3G dongle but I don't want the credit on it wasted on the connection for the TeamViewer connection. Also the the wake-on-Lan function is unreliable through the dongle.

Really thankful if someone with the know-how would take the time!

Cheers!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Workaround 1: If you run your browser inside a Virtual Machine, it's possible to assign the 3G dongle to that Virtual Machine only.

Workaround 2: Another option is to run a socks proxy server on your computer that listens locally and is instructed to use only the 3G interface for output. ( I assume this exists)

An finally, possibly the solution you were looking for - ForceBindIP:
https://www.raymond.cc/blog/bind-windows-application-to-specific-network-adapter-with-forcebindip/

If you're doing this purely to have a different IP in the browser, it may be more convenient to simply use a proxy server in the browser which you'd purchase from an anonymization service.

Comment: Hi,Thank you for takin time =) Sadly the Virtual Machine solution is not viable. I googled for the option to setup a proxy on the laptop but I can't find any solutions on how to do this and "bind" the web-browser to the dongle. I know how to do the settings for this in the web-browser but the setting up of the proxy leaves me with no answers. Maybe its me not asking the right question to google...

Comment: I don't even know if this solution will work. The solution with ForceBindIP is exactly what I'm looking for! I downloaded and tried but it seems it won't work with windows 8. I only get: 'ForceBlindIP' is not recognized as an internal or external command, operable program or batch file.. =( It says on ForceBlindIP's homepage it's compatible up to winXP because of the API's. Don't know if this is the reason it won't run on WIN 8 or not. It is Win8 x64 but if ForceBindIP was compatible shouldn't it still run on  a x64 bit machine?

Comment: YOU MY FRIEND ARE A STAR!!! =D
It worked! I did the classic idiot thing of not reading the whole test on https://www.raymond.cc/blog/bind-windows-application-to-specific-network-adapter-with-forcebindip/ 
I also had to use ForceBindIP to bind TeamViewer to the WIFI. And now I'm rocking!

Golden star to you Buddy!!